# How to set a border with round corners only to the tbody and not to the thead?

Tags: css-tables, border-radius

This is how I did the border around the tbody, however, the radius isn't being applied.

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1Data 1Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 4</td>
      <td>Data 5</td>
      <td>Data 6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUqaY.png)

I tried to wrap the tbody in a div, but then the entire tbody is under one column of the thead.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you might be able to achieve this. One way is to use the pseudo-class `not`. This will only work if you keep tbody and thead separate

```
table tbody:not(:first-child) {
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```

another way will be to use `tr:last-child td:first-child` and `tr:last-child td:last-child` with a little modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: block;
}
```

Setting the display property to block will apply the border radius.